# Correct usage of numeral-noun adjectives with nouns

Tags: nouns, adjectives, numbers

Sorry for such ridiculous question, but I cant find an answer by myself.
I have a one column row ( row with one column in it ) and two column row ( with two columns in it ). The question is : what is the correct variant ( two column row or two columns row or the third one ) and how I can find grammar rules about that?

Comment: "One-column row", "two-column row", "three-column row" and so on.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=hyphenating+multiple+word+adjectives will give you many resources.

Comment: If you look up "three ring circus" or "one horse race" in a Google search, you will see that the forms _three-ring circus_  and _one-horse race_ are  the ones most usually used. Compound adjectives used prenominally are usually hyphenated (if they're not solid) to show coherence (contrast _sweet-shop girl_ with _sweet shop girl_). But with some well-known phrases there is little need for disambiguation; you'll find the odd 'three ring circus' and 'one horse town'. Here, _two-column row_ is the sensible spelling as the phrase is relatively rare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a ['number + noun'](http://www.grammar-quizzes.com/adj_numbermodifiers.html) compound acts as an adjective, it will not take the plural form, even though the number is a plural one. The reason is that the English adjectives have no plural form.

So, the correct usage is **two-column row**, **three-column row** etc. Normally we say *A five-star hotel*, **not** *a five stars hotel*.

Comment: One does sometimes see "two weeks notice" (including in the title of at least one film), but I think it more proper to use the possessive "two weeks' notice".